# Changing height of NzSelect component

Tags: html-select, ng-zorro-antd

The height of the input field for the select defaults to 32px.

It seems to possible to change from small, large and default. However, I would like to set a custom height.

Anyone knows how to do it?

size: NzSelectSizeType = 'large';

If nzSize is set to large, the height will be 40px. I would like to set a value larger than this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by modifying this selector

```
nz-select-top-control {
    height: 3.1rem !important;
}
```

But it will modify all selects unfortunately.